# Facing an error while retrieving data on behalf of same id

Tags: mysql, node.js, join

I have 3 tables , first is 
Applicant

```
Ap_id       Username          Email            password
 1          Elen_zey     Alan@gmail.com        123456
 2          Morgan_jam    Morgan@gmail.com     443556
 3          Alex_Hales     Alex@gmail.com      534545
```

Applicant Personal Info

```
Ap_id       FirstName     LastName        Contact       CNIC
 1           Alan          Zey          214343555   4663-14334-1
 2           Morgan        Jam          984209482   2663-14334-4
 3           Alex          Hales        343453453   7663-14334-2
```

Applicant Professional Info

```
Ap_id    duration    organization     Designation   Total Experience
 1         10          10 Pearls       Intern          20 Months
 1         10          10 Pearls       DBA             20 Months
 2         36          Radium Inc       SQA             36 Months
 3         46          Sper Inc        Intern          46 Months
```

I want to retrieve applicant's email, contact number, first name and last name where Total Experience is equal and greater than 10 Months. I tried this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(aper.FirstName," ",aper.LastName)) AS 
Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ap.Email), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT aper.Contact), 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT apro.totalExperience) AS Experience FROM 
applicant_personal_info aper INNER JOIN applicant ap ON aper.ApplicantID = 
ap.ApplicantID INNER JOIN applicant_professional_info apro ON 
aper.ApplicantID = apro.ApplicantID WHERE apro.totalExperience >=10
```

I am getting result like this

```
Name : 'Alan Zey, Morgan Jam, Alex Hales',
Email : 'Alan@gmail.com, Morgan@gmail.com,Alex@gmail.com',
Contact : '214343555,984209482,343453453',
Experience : '20,36,46'
```

But i want to result like this

```
Name : Alan Zey,
Email : Alan@gmail.com,  
Contact : 214343555,
Experience : 20

Name : Morgan Jam,
Email : Mirgan@gmail.com,  
Contact : 984209482   ,
Experience : 36

Name : Alex Hales,
Email : Alex@gmail.com,  
Contact : 343453453,
Experience : 46
```

As there are multiple records in applicant professional info , any record can be used because in total experience column there is total of all duration column against same applicant ID.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Don't use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of all the `GROUP_CONCAT()` calls, they're combining all the records into a single row with comma-separated values.

Use `GROUP BY aper.ApplicantID` to get one row per applicant, and `MAX(apro.totalExperience)` to get the highest experience of all their professional info records in the final result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(aper.FirstName," ",aper.LastName) AS Name, ap.Email, aper.Contact, MAX(apro.totalExperience) AS Experience
FROM applicant_personal_info aper 
INNER JOIN applicant ap ON aper.ApplicantID = ap.ApplicantID 
INNER JOIN applicant_professional_info apro ON aper.ApplicantID = apro.ApplicantID 
WHERE apro.totalExperience >= 10
GROUP BY aper.ApplicantID
```

Comment: If i am removing Group_Concat then it is bringing results multiple times. because i have multiple records of same applicant in applicant professional info. Let say if there are 3 records against same applicant Id in applicant professional info table then this query is bringing result of that applicant 3 times. i.e redundancy is occuring

Comment: Can you show an example of that in your question, and what the desired result is when there are multiple records?

Comment: If there are multiple records for the same applicant, whicn one should be used for `Experience`?

Comment: i have updated my post and update applicant professional info table and also mentioned that which record should be used for experience. see whole post again

Comment: I've already updated my answer to show how to do it with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that he has the same total experience in both rows, or will that always be true? I don't think it matters for my answer, though.